# Setting timeouts in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I'm in two minds regarding setting timeout values for my nginx reverse proxy webserver.

A [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/configure-nginx-for-optimized-performance) by Linode suggests the following:

```
client_header_timeout  3m;
client_body_timeout    3m;
send_timeout           3m;
```

However, a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-nginx-configuration) by Digital Ocean on the same subject suggests:

```
client_body_timeout 12;
client_header_timeout 12;
keepalive_timeout 15;
send_timeout 10;
```

Moreover, the former tut recommends:

`keepalive_requests 100000;`

Whereas [another](http://www.slashroot.in/nginx-web-server-performance-tuning-how-to-do-it) optimization tut recommends:

`keepalive_requests 200;`

Clearly, not all optimization guides are created equal. It's confusing for an accidental server admin like myself.

I know benchmarking my actual environment can help, but I wanted to start with sane numbers first.

What are the pros and cons of setting these numbers really high vs really low? Clients connecting to this particular web app mostly have connectivity issues (slow mobile internet), which means that maybe I should start with a high number? Or is that not a factor? Would be great to get a recommendation on these values.

---

In case warranted, currently I've set the parameters in-question as follows in my conf file. Need help in tuning them:

```
client_body_timeout 1m;
client_header_timeout 1m;
keepalive_timeout 65;
send_timeout 30s;
keepalive_requests 3000;
```

Answer (score 1):

If unsure, use the defaults until there is a problem that you can track back to a particular setting. The defaults are meant to be a sane starting point for the needs exhibited by most users. What is best for you is dependent upon your specific traffic.

If you know you are running on a small Linode or or Droplet and the provider provides a howto it is probably useful to follow that, on that system only.

Only tweak the timeout settings if you are seeing timeout errors. These may be 504 Gateway Timeouts seen in the browser. You should also see the backend connection errors in the Nginx logs. If your research into those errors leads you to believe they're caused by timeout settings change them.

Comment: In your answer, could you also shed light on what kind of problems one ought to keep a look out for if these settings are, say, too low (or too high)?